# SharePoint Desginer 2013: Get group object by id to fill a group column in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I need help to fill a list column (type=group) within SharePoint Designer 2013, SharePoint Online.

First I created a SharePoint group with a REST request and get the ID of the group as response.

Now I need to fill a the newly created group in a custom list column (type=user or group) but I'm not able to transform the group ID to a group object.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this?

Best regards
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue with your REST code to put Group ID into list column... this is an Example show how to Post value inside a SHarepoint List.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'PutYourgroupColumn': 'YourGroupID' }),
    headers: { 
        "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-length": <length of post body>,
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "IF-MATCH": "*"
    },
    success: doSuccess,
    error: doError
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this was nearly correct.
Just changing the type to the concrete SP list type and the URL with the concrete item.

Comment: happy that I could help you with it even if this code wasn't 100% perfect ;)